# Xamarin cross platform .net2.0

Tags: xamarin

I've created a Cross platform Application for Xamarin in Visual Studio. The application is running on .NET Standard 2.0 and it's not possible to select a higher version.
Isn't possible to run a Xamarin project on a newer .NET version? The problem is that a want to install nuget packages that requires at least .NET 4.5.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing `.net` and `.net standard`. .net standard gathers many other .net platform (for example .net core, uwp, windows phone etc...) including the classical .net (from 4.5 to 4.6.1). Take a look at [this table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) to have a better understanding.
This means that you should be able to include your library that targets .net 4.5.

Now that you know that, you can define a fallback version if the library does not target .net standard. To do so add this line in your .net standard .csproj in the `PropertyGroup` node

```
<PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-win+net45+wp8+win81+wpa8</PackageTargetFallback>
```

Comment: Thanks for your info. However, the solution you suggested did not helped. I've read this article with similar actions but still not work: https://medium.com/@SicknoteSteve/nuget-targeting-both-net-standard-and-the-net-framework-326a16266ca4

Answer (score 0):

.NET Standard is a `standard`, [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/internals/net-standard) is nicely covering it. Beside that must read, here is a [compatibility table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/libraries#how-to-target-the-net-standard).

So please, read the official documentation. Setup your mind and come back with a proper question. Currently it does not make sense.

Good luck!

P.S.: Currently you are trying to use an outdated library that does not support .NET Standard, you might want to look for alternatives.